# How to search for a match inside list items?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following issue:

I have **Add** button which is adding something like tag and i want to check if the tag is already added. 
Here is my try... but not successful

```
 if ($(".selected_tags li span").find($("#tagname").val())) {
    alert("Tag already exists!");
    }
```

I suppose that I'm not using the find function properly...

Thanks in advance,

Z.

EDIT: When I look at the answers I see that you misunderstand me. That's m fault!
So here is the case with more details: I have an input field , and the ADD button. The user types tag name inside the field and when he press the Add button i need to check if he already added a tag with that name inside the list with the tag names.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="new_article_add_tags_wrap">
            <input type="search" class="search_new_article_tags" id="tagname"/>
            <button class="add_new_article_tag_btn" id="add_tagname"><span>Add</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="new_article_selected_tags_container">
            <ul class="selected_tags">
                <li>
                    <span>Algorithm</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Graph Theory</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

So each time when the user press the Add button i need to perform a simple search thru all spans to check if the tag is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't have more than one element with a specific id, if you're looking for the presence of an element with id `tagname`, you should simply test

```
if ($("#tagname").length) {
    alert("Tag already exists!");
}
```

If what you want to search is the tag, not the id, use

```
if ($(".selected_tags li span tagname").length) {
    alert("Tag already exists!");
}
```

If you want to look for a tag that is given by the value of an input whose id is `tagname`, as a descendant of `".selected_tags li span"` elements, use lenght like this

```
if ($($('#tagname').val(), ".selected_tags li span").length) {
```

Answer (score 1):

try `length()`...

```
if ($(".selected_tags li span").find($("#tagname").val()).length > 0) {
  alert("Tag already exists!");
}
```

wihtout using find()

```
if ($(".selected_tags li span tagname").length > 0) {
  alert("Tag already exists!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors, should be:

```
if ($(".selected_tags li span").find("#tagname").length) {
    alert("Tag already exists!");
}
```